# Add a one dimensional array to a more dimensional array c#

Tags: c#, arrays

i have two arrays. One is my operational array (30 values in only one dimention) and the other one is my destination array 30 values and 2 dimentions. Is there a way to add the operation array as an dimention to the destination array without using foreach function?

```
array one:
xxx...xx
```

adds to:

```
array two:
ttt...tt
ddd...dd
...
xxx...xx
```

Answer (score 0):

Array size is fixed once you create it. The multidimensional array will have to be a list of arrays so you can do something like this.

```cs
var operationalArray = new int[30];
var destinationArray = new List<int[]>();

destinationArray.Add(operationalArray);
```